# Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC Create NLog table schema with code-first migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, nlog

I am using NLog for my Asp.Net Core 3.1 web application.
I am trying to use a migration to create the table for the Logging.

I am trying to convert this script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] (
     [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [Application] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
     [Logged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
     [Level] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
     [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
     [Logger] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
     [Callsite] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
     WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

To a migration, but I do not know how to handle the constraint part. Do I need to add some code to account for that constraint part, or just go:

> add-migration AddedLogTable
>
> update-database

So far I have create the table model:

```
public class Log
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Application { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Logged { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Level { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Logger { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Callsite { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the db context class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Log> DbLogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            //builder.Seed();

             foreach(var foreignKey in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(e=> e.GetForeignKeys()))
             {
                foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
                
             }
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate some help with this please.

Comment: What isn't working? Your question is a bit vague

Comment: @Julian I am just wondering if I should add some code into the migration to account for that Constraint part, or just simply add-migration and then update-database